# How can I get rotated rectangle corner points from side points

Tags: math

Say I have a set of four or more points that are on the perimeter of a rectangle, and that the rectangle is rotated by some unknown amount.  I know that at least one point is on each side of the rectangle.  One arbitrary side point is designated (0, 0), and the other points are the distance from this starting point.  How can I get the non-rotated corner points of this rectangle?

Comment: 4 points are not sufficient.  Imagine a square and the four input points are its corners.  Now draw a diamond such that the four points are each edge's midpoint.  Any four points that are the exact corners of a rectangle can have any number of other rectangles drawn such that those points are NOT the corners (and all of them will be different once rotated to orthogonal).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Won't all the rectangles in your example have the same height and width?  If so, that is fine, after the rectangle is rotated to orthogonal I can recalculate the relative offsets for each point based on a top-left value of (0, 0).

Comment: you prove there's not a unique solution on paper: draw a square, now draw a rotated rectangle (of different height and width) on top of your square.  choose 4 of the intersection points. you have 4 points that are on 2 clearly different rectangles (and there's way more than 2 rectangles that will satisfy your 4 points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you're not trying to find a unique solution:

1. rotate your points around 0,0 until the top-most, bottom-most,
   left-most, and right-most points are all different points
2. draw horizontal lines through the top-most and bottom-most, and vertical lines through the left-most and right-most
3. you're done

```js
var points = [];
var bs = document.body.style;
var ds = document.documentElement.style;
bs.height = bs.width = ds.height = ds.width = "100%";
bs.border = bs.margin = bs.padding = 0;
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
c.style.display = "block";
c.addEventListener("mousedown", addPoint, false);
document.body.appendChild(c);
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var interval;

function addPoint(e) {
    if (points.length >= 4) points = [];
    points.push({
        x: e.x - c.offsetLeft,
        y: e.y - c.offsetTop
    });
    while (points.length > 4) points.shift();
    redraw();
}
function rotateAround(a, b, r) {
    d = {x:a.x - b.x, y:a.y - b.y};
    return {
        x: b.x + Math.cos(r) * d.x - Math.sin(r) * d.y,
        y: b.y + Math.cos(r) * d.y + Math.sin(r) * d.x
    }
}
function drawPoint(p) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

var last_few = [];

function redraw() {
    if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
    last_few = [];
    c.width = window.innerWidth;
    c.height = window.innerHeight;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200, 200, 200)";
    ctx.font = "40px serif";
    if (points.length < 4) {
        ctx.fillText("click " + (4 - points.length) + " times", 20, 40);
        points.forEach(drawPoint);
    } else {
        var average = {x:0, y:0};
        points.forEach(function (p) {
            average.x += p.x / 4;
            average.y += p.y / 4;
        });
        var step = 0;
        interval = setInterval(function () {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
         ctx.fillText("click anywhere to start over", 20, 40);
            last_few.forEach(function(r) {
             ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(200,255,200)";
                ctx.save();
                ctx.translate(average.x, average.y);
                ctx.rotate((step -r.step) * Math.PI / 180);
             ctx.strokeRect(r.lm - average.x, r.tm - average.y, (r.rm - r.lm), (r.bm - r.tm));
                ctx.restore();
            });
            var tm = Infinity;
            var bm = -Infinity;
            var lm = Infinity;
            var rm = -Infinity;
            points.forEach(function (p) {
                p = rotateAround(p, average, step * Math.PI / 180);
                drawPoint(p);
                tm = Math.min(p.y, tm);
                bm = Math.max(p.y, bm);
                lm = Math.min(p.x, lm);
                rm = Math.max(p.x, rm);
            });
            if (points.every(function (p) {
                p = rotateAround(p, average, step * Math.PI / 180);
                return (p.x == lm) || (p.x == rm) || (p.y == tm) || (p.y == bm);
            })) {
                ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,255,0)";
                ctx.strokeRect(lm, tm, (rm - lm), (bm - tm));
                last_few.push({tm:tm, bm:bm, lm:lm, rm:rm, step:step});
                while(last_few.length > 30) last_few.shift();
            } else {
                ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
                ctx.strokeRect(lm, tm, (rm - lm), (bm - tm));
            }
            step++;
        }, 30);
    }
}

window.onresize = redraw;
redraw();
```

Comment: Instead of your step 1, what if I measured the horizontal distance between points while doing the rotation.  Would it be true that the rectangle is not rotated where this measurement was the greatest?  E.g. that would be the point where the rectangle is aligned with a 2D grid, with the width >= than the height.

Comment: 1) Is a useless instruction, the 4 points are already different.  2) is unhelpful because the points may not be corners.

Comment: @Kevin finding the greatest distance won't necessarily help you find a side for each point; there are ways to arrange the points such that the longest distance is between points on adjacent sides

Comment: @Draco18s 1) Imagine a very wide rectangle rotated 45º clockwise with points chosen midway on each of the 4 sides, the top-most and left-most point are the same point. 2) doesn't assume they're on corners, it assumes they're on sides

Comment: @dtudury Imagine a rectangle that is 1.3 times wider with 44 degrees of rotation with the four points being the four points at which my rectangle intersects yours.  How does this algorithm pick between both of these valid solutions given those four points?

Comment: @Draco18s it doesn't pick between them: "assuming you're not trying to find a unique solution...". when you rotate the points back 44º it finds your original rectangle; when you rotate the points back 44.1º it finds a slightly different but still valid rectangle.  what you said in the first comment on the original post is totally true.

Comment: @dtudury My rectangle is wider than your rectangle, therefore when rotated back 44 degrees it has different corner points than your rectangle when rotated back 45 degrees.  As I said, mine is 30% wider than yours.  Or how about a visual example. http://s9.postimg.org/gc1whuean/rectangles.gif

Comment: @dtudury, That's a great animation, thanks for posting.  I ended up implementing a solution based on what you proposed.  To help get the best fit I allow the user to specify the target side for the points (this information is available).  Also I am drawing the points on a background image, so what I also do is compare the aspect ratio of the rectangle created from the rotated points to the aspect ratio of the background image, and this allows me to get a good fit.  Thanks to you and Draco18s for your help.